# How to bind multiple events to the same input and make it work harmoniously in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a value in input box which needs to be sent to the server to fetch related values and to be displayed as a drop down list below.

The api call needs to be triggered on three conditions after the user has entered value

1. The user can press a search icon
2. The user can press a enter key
3. If user didnt do any of the above two options I need to fire api call automatically after a idle time of 3 secs

Below is the stripped version of the code I have without api calls. I have also created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Umamaheswaran1990/pen/jARBBN?editors=1010#0) for this

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="name"
           ng-change="actualWork('ngChange')" enter-key="actualWork('enterKey')" ng-model-options="{debounce : 3000}"/>
    <button ng-click="actualWork('click')">Do Work</button>
    {{message}}

<script>
angular.module('myApp',[]);

    angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
     $scope.name = "Test";
      $scope.actualWork = function(source){
        $scope.message = $scope.name + " from "+source;
      }

    });

    angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('enterKey', function () {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                    if (event.which === 13) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.$eval(attrs.enterKey);
                        });

                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            };
        });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code ng-change will be fired even irrespective of whether the user presses the button or enter key.

Does someone let me know how to stop ng-change from firing if enter/button is pressed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/ehmssss/pen/EyJmVE?editors=1010#anon-signup

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="actualWork('enter')">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"
           ng-change="actualWork('ngChange')" ng-model-options="{debounce : 5000}"/>
    </form>
    <button type='submit' ng-click="actualWork('click')">Do Work</button>
    {{message}}
  </body>
```

i separated the button and added a form submit